# Play() function doesn't work on keyboard input (up and down arrow) QML

Tags: video, keyboard, qml, focus

As described in the title, I am unable to play video in `onFocusChanged` component on keyboard input (up and down arrow). I am not exactly sure if the problem is in `focus`,  `play()` function or something else. I tried many different ways to make it work including `ForceActiveFocus`. It works on click (the video is playing on click) so I doubt the problem is in url. I have installed K-Lite Codec Pack.
Here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtMultimedia 5.15
import QtLocation 5.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    XmlListModel {
        id: xmlModel
        source: "channels.xml"
        query: "/channels/channel"

        XmlRole { name: "uid"; query: "uid/string()" }
        XmlRole { name: "icon"; query: "icon/string()" }
        XmlRole { name: "start"; query: "start/string()" }
        XmlRole { name: "end"; query: "start/string()" }
        XmlRole { name: "url"; query: "url/string()" }

     }

    GridLayout{
        id:grid
       // anchors.fill:parent
        width:parent.width
        height:parent.height
        rows:2
        columns:1
        rowSpacing: 5
        flow:GridLayout.TopToBottom


        Video{
                 id:video
                 width:500
                 height:300
                // anchors.left:parent.left
                 autoLoad: true
                 autoPlay: true

        }

        ListView{
            id:list
            model:xmlModel
            width:video.width
            height:parent.height-video.height
            spacing:2
            Layout.fillHeight:true
            focus:true
            keyNavigationEnabled: true
            keyNavigationWraps:true


            delegate:
                Rectangle{
                    id:rect1
                    width:75
                    height:75
                    color:"#333333"


                    Image{
                        id:img1
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        source:icon
                    }


                    Rectangle{
                        id:rect2
                        width:video.width-rect1.width
                        height:rect1.height
                        anchors.left:rect1.right
                        //color:"#333333"
                        border.color: "darkgray"
                        color:focus?"red":"#333333"

                        onFocusChanged:{ //this is where I think the problem lies, but it seems fine
                            if(focus){
                              console.log("fokus")
                              list.currentIndex=index
                              video.source=url
                              video.play()
                            }
                        }

                        Text{
                            id:text1
                            text:uid
                            color:'white'
                            font.pointSize: 14
                            x:15
                            y:17
                            anchors.left: parent

                        }


                    MouseArea{
                        id:mouse
                        anchors.fill:parent

                        onClicked:{
                            list.currentIndex=index
                            //console.log("klik"+ url)
                            video.source=url
                            video.play()
                            //console.log(video.playbackState)
                        }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
         }
      }
```

So, when I press up and down the focus is changed to another rectangle in ListView, but the video isn't playing. Any help would be appreciated.

p.s. `Channels.xml` is a xml file in my project that contains list of movies with their id's, url's and other data that I have to include in this project. It is available here:
https://github.com/uniqcast/challenge-qml/blob/master/simple-tv/subtask-2/channels.xml
Just copy it and paste it into newly created xml file in qt creator under your project (Add new file->general->new empty file-> name it "channels.xml" and paste the xml code if you want to run and test the code.

Edit: I managed to think of a 'workaround' by placing this code:

```
                         onFocusChanged:{
                            if(focus){
                              console.log("fokus")
                              list.currentIndex=index
                              video.source=url
                              video.play()
                            }
                        }
```

below `rect1` rectangle and it works. It triggers the wrong rectangle though, but the video is playing upon pressing up or down key on keyboard.
I didn't post this as an answer simply because it is a 'workaround' and it does not trigger focus on the right rectangle.

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it. I can't Run and Test the code that you put in question .what is `channels.xml` file?

Comment: My guess is that it's because of this line: `rect.currentIndex=index`. It doesn't look like `rect` has a property named `currentIndex`, so it will stop processing the rest of that code. Change it to `list.currentIndex` and see if it works.

Comment: @JarMan sorry, this is a leftover from trying different solutions. The original is in fact ```list.currentIndex=index``` as you sugested and that is not working. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R this is all my code and it can be tested. The only thing that I can't post here is ```channels.xml```. It is available here: https://github.com/uniqcast/challenge-qml/blob/master/simple-tv/subtask-2/channels.xml. You can just copy it and paste it into newly created xml file in qt creator under your project (Add new file->general->new empty file-> name it "channels.xml" and paste the xml code.